# What is the largest c for which Fn = omega(2^cn)?

Tags: time-complexity

Here Fn is the Fibonacci function.

I tried to go about this by saying c = F(n+1)/F(n) but that ratio goes larger as we look at greater values of n.

Comment: It depends on the implementation of the Fibonacci algorithm. e.g. Binet's formula calculates Fibonacci values in O(1) time complexity.

Comment: The growth complexity of the Fibonacci number `Fn` with respect to index `n` is `Θ(1.618^n)` - precise value is `(1 + sqrt(5)) / 2`, the Golden Ratio. So you need `2^c < 1.618...`. If this is what you're asking, then `time-complexity` might be the wrong tag.